# Configure pymongo to use string _id instead of ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, meteor, pymongo

I'm using `pymongo` to seed a database with old information from a different system, and I have a lot of queries like this:

```
studentId = studentsRemote.insert({'price': price})
```

In the actual python script, that `studentId` prints as a string, but in the javascript Meteor application I'm using this data in, it shows up everywhere as `ObjectId(...)`.

**I want to configure `pymongo` to generate the `_id` as a string and not bother with ObjectId's**

Any objects I create with the Meteor specification will use the string format, and not the ObjectId format. I don't want to have mixing of id types in my application, because it's causing me interoperability headaches.

I'm aware I can [create ObjectId's from Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#collection_object_id) but frankly I'd much rather use the string format. It's the Meteor default, it's much simpler, and [I can't find any good reason to use ObjectId's in my particular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299015/generation-of-id-vs-objectid-autogeneration-in-mongodb).

[The `valueOf()` mongo function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/) or something similar could parse the `_id` and be used to update the document once it's in the database, but it would be nice to have something more direct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It ended up being fairly simple.

The [`son_manipulator` module](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/son_manipulator.html) can be used to change incoming documents to a different form. Most of the time [this is used to encode custom objects](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/custom_type.html), but it worked for this as well.

With the manipulator in place, it was just a matter of [calling the `str()` function on the ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html) to make the transformation.

```py
from pymongo.son_manipulator import SONManipulator
class ObjectIdManipulator(SONManipulator):
    def transform_incoming(self, son, collection):
        son[u'_id'] = str(son[u'_id'])      
        return son

db.add_son_manipulator(ObjectIdManipulator())
```

Comment: It appears that add_son_manipulator() is now deprecated. I'm having trouble finding a suitable alternative. Does anyone have any ideas? It doesn't seem to be working in Python 2.7.10 anyway. I added a breakpoint and a print statement inside of the transform_incoming() method the code never reaches that point.

Answer (score 6):

in .py files:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
......
kvdict['_id'] = str(ObjectId())
......
mongoCollection.insert(kvdict)
```

it's ok!

Comment: This is working... adding the _id to the dict, force mongo to use that _id and not the default ObjectId()