# Pymongo Insert Doc with String ID's rather than ObjectIDs

Tags: python, mongodb, meteor, pymongo

I am trying to get pymongo to insert new documents which have id's in string format rather than ObjectId's.  The app I am building integrates meteor and python and meteor inserts string id's so having to work with both string and Objectids adds complexity.

Example:

Meteor-inserted doc:

```
{
    "_id" : "22FHWpvqrAeyfvh7B"
}
```

Pymongo-inserted doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880387d1fd21c2dc66e9b7d")
}
```

Comment: I.n Loki up9mjfhhkjflkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just switch your Meteor app to insert ObjectIds instead of strings.  Just use the `idGeneration` option property and set the value to `MONGO`.

Here is an example.

```
var todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos', {
  idGeneration: 'MONGO'
});
```

It is described in the Meteor docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection).

Or, if you want Meteir to keep strings and can't figure out how to configure Pymongo to store as strings, then you can do the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131795/configure-pymongo-to-use-string-id-instead-of-objectid) to convert between ObjectIds and strings in Pymongo..

Comment: thanks Jordan!  this helps.  the approach you linked is working great!  first, generate an ObjectId, then extract the string value, then insert into pymongo with an explicit "_id" field"

str(ObjectId())